# How to place lookup table in the function body?

Tags: c++, optimization

Let's say I have a function that needs to do a lookup in a tiny lookup table.

If we write `static constexpr uint8_t lookup_table[]` inside the function body, I see that the lookup table is loaded in memory quite far away from `foo` on my machine (difference is ~3k bytes)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Returns |x - y|
uint64_t abs_diff(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    return std::min(x - y, y - x);
}

void foo() {
    static constexpr uint8_t lookup_table[] = {0xaa, 0xab, 0xba, 0xca, 0xac};
    uint64_t foo_addr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&foo);

    asm __volatile__ ("jmp my_hack");
    asm __volatile__ ("inline_lookup_table:");
    asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xaa");
    asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xab");
    asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xba");
    asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xca");
    asm __volatile__ (".byte 0xac");
    asm __volatile__ ("my_hack:");
    uint8_t* inline_lookup_table;
    asm ("lea inline_lookup_table(%%rip), %0;"
        :"=r"(inline_lookup_table)
        :
        :);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << "Table contents: " << hex << (uint64_t)inline_lookup_table[i] << dec << endl;       
    }

    cout << "static constexpr difference: " << abs_diff(foo_addr, reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&lookup_table[0])) << endl;
    cout << "inline assembly difference: " << abs_diff(foo_addr,  reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(inline_lookup_table)) << endl;
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Here is a test program that I wrote.

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -O3 kek.cc -o a.out && ./a.out
Table contents: aa
Table contents: ab
Table contents: ba
Table contents: ca
Table contents: ac
# static constexpr gets placed quite far away
static constexpr difference: 3648
# inline lookup table is placed right inside the function.
inline assembly difference: 16
```

Is it possible to ask the compiler to place the lookup table as close to the `foo` as possible and avoid the unportable asm magic? This is optimization-related (trying to place the lookup table in the same cache line as the code)

I have tried using some asm magic, but that's really ugly and not quite portable...

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the chances of there being a "portable" way of doing something like this are zero.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the compiler will do here. You'd have to test case by case to see where the code is placed by the compiler then conform to it. Hackish techniques like this are just not portable nor standard.

Comment: "_trying to place the lookup table in the same cache line as the code_": What good would that be? Normally code and data are in different pages (which are 4kB typically btw. so that fits your observation). Processors have separate L1 instruction and data caches (and TLBs). I am not even sure that putting data and instructions together in a cache line wouldn't negatively impact the CPU's work, because that is not what they are optimized for. What you want to do here is very unusual. What do you intent to achieve or what do you base the intended performance benefit on?